# Stop triggering AlarmManager regularly at specific time

Tags: android, broadcastreceiver, alarmmanager, android-pendingintent, android-calendar

I am using AlarmManager with in my app. The first step was to support an alarm which starts daily at x o'clock and fires with an interval of n minutes. This is how it works:

```
Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
calendar.setTimeInMillis(System.currentTimeMillis());
calendar.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, fromHours);
calendar.set(Calendar.MINUTE, fromMinutes);

long fromTime = calendar.getTimeInMillis();

Intent intent = new Intent(context, MyAlarmReceiver.class);
intent.putExtra(ID, id);
PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(context, id, intent, 0);
AlarmManager alarmManager = (AlarmManager) context.getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
alarmManager.setRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, fromTime, 1000 * 60 * intervalMinutes, pendingIntent);
```

But now in the second step I wish to support to set a daily end time when the alarm stops to fire. So I need to implement something like:

```
alarmManager.setRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, fromTime, toTime, 1000 * 60 * intervalMinutes, pendingIntent);
```

How can I do that? Canceling the timer when `System.currentMillis() > toTime` will not work as desired because this will cancel the timer forever. But the next day it has to fire again.

Comment: Save the ending time in `SharedPreferences`, check it in your `MyAlarmReceiver`, and if it has passed, cancel the alarm instead of whatever function the Receiver performs otherwise.

Comment: That's what I meant with if I cancel the timer, then it does not fire the next day.

Comment: Oops, sorry, I edited that comment like three times, and accidentally omitted the important part in the end. When you cancel the current repeating alarm, just set a new one for the desired starting time the next day.